# I am getting syntax error while using foreach in javascipt. I am trying to create a function to increase and decrease the text size on my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code I am trying to use to create a function to increase/ decrease text size on my page:
this is the error i get: "main.js (65,19) Syntax error"

```js
function changeFontsize(type)
{
    let ids = ["#h3", "#p" ];
    
    ids.forEach( id => {
        
        let el = document.querySelector(id);
        
        
        let fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
        
        
        fontSize = parseFloat.(fontSize);
        
        
        if(type === "increase")
        {
            el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 5) + "px" ;
            
        }
        else 
        {
           el.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 5) +"px";    
        
        }
        
        
        
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.` after `parseFloat`

Comment: If there is an **error**, can you please **share it** in the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error is in this line:

```js
parseFloat.(fontSize)
```

Remove `.`:

```js
parseFloat(fontSize)
```

Comment: I tried fixing that but it is still giving me a syntax error and says that the error is in this line:  ids.forEach( id => {

Comment: Can you add that error in the question?

Comment: I've added the error to the question

Comment: The error says that's the syntax error in the `main.js` . Can you add whole `main.js` file in the question?

Comment: I get the same error even if I try to implement just this code snippet in a <script> tag of an HTML file

Comment: It works if you put `<script>` tag in HTML with the code snippet. Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/hn7qpetL/

Comment: I tried getting it to work but getting this error now:  "<a class='gotoLine' href='#54:29'>54:29</a> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Comment: my code can be found at : https://jsfiddle.net/hn7qpetL/

Comment: i tried this code : <html>
<body>
<button onclick = "changeFontsize('increase')">
A+
</button>
</button>
<h3>
Hello
</h3>
<p>
Hello world 
</p>
<script>
  JS code in the question
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqxk2vop/1/ : you can find the whole code here, srry the link provided above is incorrect

Comment: I checked the code. The problem is in this line: `let ids = ["#h3", "#p"];` . Change it to: `let ids = ["h3", "p"];`.

Comment: thank you so much, I've been struggling all day to get this working, it works fine now

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Also, i was trying to implement this code with more than one <p> tags and what it does is that, it only applies it to the first <p> in the code. Can you suggest how this problem can be fixed?

Comment: here is the link to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/fsapzbcr/ it applies to the first two lines only and not to the paragraph

Comment: You can instead search with `getElementsByTagName`. That will return an array of elements with that `tag` and then you can apply the logic to each element. Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/whptsrL4/